Which Storage Shows Validator and Nominator Data in v1.11.0?
Previously, I retrieved validator and nominator data from the eraStakers storage. However, after upgrading my code to version 1.11.0, I'm unsure which storage now provides the data for validators and their nominators. Can someone clarify?"
